# Show the [guest] the door

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

The [guest](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest) is unwelcome and would benefit from clarification.  As it stands "guest" is simply too vague to be useful.

We have [guest-additions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest-additions), but this tag might do with being split into [guest-accounts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest-accounts) and [guest-vm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest-vm) for virtualised guest systems, though others might be more suitable.

Comment: Mods can't do that by themselves?

Comment: @AndroidDev Mods cannot specifically delete tags, no.  But even if we could we shouldn't do it without community consensus.

Comment: VirtualBox [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) is  a program that can be installed inside a VirtualBox VM. The VMware equivalent is VMware tools, so the two VMware questions tagged [tag:guest-editions] should be tagged [tag:vmware-tools] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [guest](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest) has been escorted out of the building.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [host-vm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/host-vm) either, so I suggest that questions applicable for a [guest-vm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest-vm) be retagged with [virtual-machine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with the singular form [guest-account](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guest-account), as [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=guest%20account%2C%20guest%20accounts) shows it's far more popular.

<sub>(Split into two answers since it's a different proposal.)</sub>

Comment: In all honesty a single answer or just comments would have been better as this is mainly about getting rid of the guest tag and the 28 upvotes seems to suggest that the community agrees it should be gone. I agree with your points in general though. I'll start the ball rolling soon.

Comment: @Mokubai apologies, I tried to search meta for for how to handle this best, but could not find anything. Anyway, I already removed the VMware tag for one of the [tag:guest-additions] questions; the other turned out to be about both VirtualBox and VMware, so I did not remove it from that one. I also added a tag wiki for [tag:guest-additions].